# How do I display a custom field in an existing form on the front end?

Tags: custom-field, metabox, front-end

I just have one custom field (from metabox.io) that I need added to the front end of an existing form. 
Can someone just clarify the steps. I tried following this tutorial: https://voodoopress.com/add-a-meta-box-to-use-custom-fields-on-front-end-post-form/
but am confused with the steps such as adding the input fields into an array. Do we only need to do this if we're creating a form from scratch? Will this array already exist if I'm using an existing form?

I just need someone to clarify how to get the values of the metabox into an input field on the form and saving the data if the user edits the page and also if they submit.

**UPDATE

Admin code:

```
function get_dates( $meta_boxes ) {
$prefix = 'prefix-';

$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id' => 'mydates',
    'title' => esc_html__( 'Dates Available', 'mydates' ),
    'post_types' => array( 'listing', 'page' ),
    'context' => 'side',
    'priority' => 'low',
    'autosave' => false,
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'id' => $prefix . 'mydates',
            'type' => 'date',
            'name' => esc_html__( 'Date Picker', 'mydates' ),
            'desc' => esc_html__( 'Select multiple dates', 'mydates' ),
            'clone' => true,
            'sort_clone' => true,
        ),
    ),
);

return $meta_boxes;
}
add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'get_dates' );
```

Front end form (editing and submitting the form)

```
$mydates = if(isset($_POST['prefix-mydates'])) echo $_POST['prefix-mydates'];


<fieldset>
<input type="text" value=""  id="prefix-mydates" class="rwmb-date hasDatepicker" size="60" tabindex="20" name="prefix-mydates">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Try the [generator](https://metabox.io/online-generator/) or see this [sample on manually creating custom fields](https://docs.metabox.io/quick-start/#creating-a-simple-meta-box-manually). On the front-end, you can use `rwmb_meta()` to [display the field value](https://docs.metabox.io/quick-start/#displaying-fields).

Comment: But how do you add the Metabox fields to a front end form that already exists.  I already have the admin Metabox with the custom field and I also have a page that displays the value of the Metabox on the front end. How do I get the custom field on the back end to appear on a front end form. I know there’s the frontend form extension for mb but I just have one custom field I need to add.

Comment: Can you share your code? The admin meta box and the existing front-end form.

Comment: just added the code

Comment: Check my answer. Hopefully that's what you wanted, and that it works for you, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

In the template file (used with that existing form), *before* the `get_header();` call/line, add this code:

```
global $my_dates_MB;

// If you changed the meta box ID (i.e. mydates), change it also below.
add_filter( 'rwmb_show_mydates', '__return_false' );

$meta_boxes = get_dates( [] );
$my_dates_MB = rwmb_get_meta_box( $meta_boxes[0] );

if ( isset( $_POST['my_dates_post_ID'] ) ) {
    // Save the meta data.
    $my_dates_MB->save_post( $_POST['my_dates_post_ID'] );
}

// Enqueue styles and scripts.
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', [ $my_dates_MB, 'enqueue' ] );
//$my_dates_MB->enqueue();
```

Then replace this:

```
$mydates = if(isset($_POST['prefix-mydates'])) echo $_POST['prefix-mydates'];


<fieldset>
<input type="text" value=""  id="prefix-mydates" class="rwmb-date hasDatepicker" size="60" tabindex="20" name="prefix-mydates">
</fieldset>
```

..with this:
(**UPDATED; May 02 2018**)

```
<?php
global $my_dates_MB;

// Get the current post ID.
$post_id = get_the_ID();

// Set the post ID for the "meta box".
$my_dates_MB->set_object_id( $post_id );

// Show the meta box.
$my_dates_MB->show();
?>

<input type="hidden" name="my_dates_post_ID" value="<?php echo $post_id; ?>" />
```

That will print the whole "meta box" as defined in your custom `get_dates()` function (btw, change its name to something unique), but that should not be an issue since the meta box has just one field.

You'd get something like this: (not including the "Submit" button)

[image]

Comment: It still seems to not be working for me. It displays it on the page now, but the input field isn't using the date picker and when I click +add more, it doesn't do anything. Not sure if this could be why, but it won't place itself within the div even though I've placed the code within a div.

Comment: Sounds to me like a jQuery/JS/scripts conflict(s). Did you try to view the browser console, to see if there are errors related to the date picker script or library?

Comment: Just checked, there's no errors about the datepicker or library.

Comment: Did you add/use the exact code in my answer, or did you alter it in any way? The Meta Box stylesheet and script files may not be loaded on the page.

Comment: Yep, used the same code. This form is part of another plugin by the way, so I'm not sure if that's why the scripts and styles aren't loading?

Comment: Could be. What plugin is that? Perhaps I can check it.

Comment: listingpro-plugin

Comment: I didn't check the plugin; but please see the updated answer.

Comment: $my_dates_mb->show(); is causing issues (blank white page)

Comment: the scripts aren't loading either even though I placed the exact code above the get_header();

Comment: Sorry about the `$my_dates_MB`. I actually made it a `global` variable, but I didn't include it as global in the answer. Would you mind trying again? In case the scripts would be magically loaded now?..

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work either...

Comment: Ok, I still have some options. Or one option that should really work. I'll update the answer soon.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please remove the code you added in the template (the one before the `get_header()` line), and try the one I added to the answer.

Comment: this one didn't work either

Comment: Well then, I'm giving up.. sorry about that, but I'm not able to test the listingpro-plugin for the time being. I've also rolled back the answer to the previous version (2 days ago). Hopefully the answer would help others. =)

Comment: The field displays properly now with your code, it was an issue with my script. The only thing that doesn't work now is the saving part. It doesn't seem to be saving to the admin metabox or displaying on the front end page that shows the metabox data.

Comment: Try the updated code. (Marked "UPDATED")

Comment: It still seems to not be working, could you explain a bit about what the hidden input does? The form doesn't  save the data I've added in the back end into any fields, and the display page only shows the data I've added on the backend.

Comment: Do I need to do anything to the backend template and display page template to get them to speak to the form?

Comment: The hidden `input` stores the ID of the post where the custom field was attached to. It is also an indicator that the custom field was changed via manual input on the front-end, and that it was for the post with the specified ID (in the hidden `input`). Which means, if the input was submitted, then we can save the changes.

Comment: So, if in the form (i.e. the page source or HTML) you see `<input type="hidden" name="my_dates_post_ID" value="123" />`, then the `$_POST['my_dates_post_ID']` would be `123` after you submit the form. Try this - add `echo $_POST['my_dates_post_ID'];` before this: `$my_dates_MB->save_post( $_POST['my_dates_post_ID'] );` - and see if the values match.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76899/discussion-between-abc021-and-sally-cj).